# ordenar consulta por dos variables en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

como puedo ordenar la siguiente consulta por medio de 2 variables diferentes de una misma tabla, para que quede de mayor a menor:

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$sql2="select * from detalle_fac, precios where fk_factura='$factura' and detalle_fac.fk_producto=precios.id_pre ORDER BY precios.tamano_one DESC";
```

Esa consulta esta ordenada por la variable: precios.tamano_one pero tambien necesito ordenarla por otra variable que seria la siguiente:

precios.tamano_two

de mayor a menor, osea el primer orden seria tamano_one y el segundo orden seria el tamano_two como puedo hacerlo?

Mi consulta ordenada por la variable tamano_one da como resultado lo siguiente:

VARIABLES:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces la idea es que quede ordenada por tamano_one de mayor a menor y asi mismo por tamano_two de mayor a menor.

OK, complementando la respuesta de fernando asi queda mi consulta con la respuesta de fernando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar diferentes órdenes entre campos de la misma tabla.

Al final esto sería ordenar así:

```
$sql2="select * from detalle_fac, precios where fk_factura='$factura' and detalle_fac.fk_producto=precios.id_pre ORDER BY precios.tamano_one DESC, precios.tamano_two DESC";
```

Esta consulta te ordenerá primero tus resultados por el campo `precios.tamano_one` de forma descendente, luego ordenerá por el campo `precios.tamano_two` de forma descendente `DESC`  (mayor a menor)

Te dejo como referencia esta [página](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) para que conozcas más sobre cómo ordenar por uno o más campos.

Comment: Buenas Fernando Torres ya acabo de editar mi pregunta para que sea mas clara.

Comment: Hola, estrada, mi respuesta pudiera seguir siendo válida, al final, mejor, ¿por qué no nos haces un dibujo u otro tipo de ejemplo con el resultado esperado, tal como pusiste el ejemplo gráfico de lo que tienes ahora? Así a lo mejor también te puedo ayudar a enfocar tu pregunta y a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Hola, Fernando Torres listo ya edite mi pregunta para que este aun mas clara muchas gracias.

Comment: jajaja, me acabo de dar de cuenta que ya esta bien ordenada con tu consulta, muchas gracias por la respuesta fue de gran ayuda. :)

Comment: ¡Por nada! Qué bueno que ya pudiste ordenarlo correctamente. ¡Saludos!